wifi issue in Ubuntu 24.04.1
Hi there i am currently using Ubuntu version 24.04.1 on my hp 15s device I am facing an issue that wifi adapter /pcle not found after purchasing an wifi dongle still I am facing this issue, however  I updated my driver removed it and installed it again, but it's still not working.

